# Memory leaks in SharePoint hosted single page app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, memory-leak

I am developing a SharePoint 2013 hosted app and use REST and/or CSOM queries to retrieve items from lists and use them on a single page app (SAP). Because the page is not refreshing, big amounts of memory leaks that otherwise wouldn't be a problem become a huge issue and the app reaches its maximum allowed memory and crashes. I use IE Developer Tools to monitor the memory and compare snapshots. Looks like jQuery is caching the data that I put on the view, including the various handlers, and every time I change the data on my view as much as 7 MB is retained. I am attaching an image of the details and where I traced a circular reference on a function that is abbreviated. I am quite lost about what I can do here. Is there a magical way to prevent (if this is even relevant here) jQuery from caching some or all of the data? Any idea or info is much appreciated.
[image: Screenshot of the circular reference b -> b* that I traced inside the data cache of jQuery]

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @Arsalan Shahid: I really don't wait for an error message. I am monitoring the memory from the Task Manager and the app starts at around 230 MB and goes up to 1,600 MB then because the app doesn't have enough memory the calls to the server start failing